# Document set ID heritage

Tags: document-set

a simple question but probably complex answer :)
Is there any way which allows me to share a unique identifying information which is common between the "Set" and each "document" which is recorded in the set?
Ideally without development.

Many thanks to all of you
Regards,
Tzelos

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into Shared columns that allow sync of values from set to all documents in the set? Not sure if you are looking for something else.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for your answer.
In fact this sync of metadata doesn't work. Probably a setting at entreprise level? I contacted our sharepoint admin for this.
Nevertheless I'm wondering if there is materialised somewhere a kind of link 'parent-to-child' or a 'node' concept

Many thanks again to the community